# sql server query current date from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to find few data from SQL Server that only query by current date. The purpose is to view today transaction only

Here is my code

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Student.studentProfile
WHERE TransactionDate = curdate()
```

RESULT

> Curdate is not a recongined built-in function name

Comment: In T-SQL `GETDATE()` would be used.

Comment: @C-Pound Guru, This question is for SQL Server not MySQL

Comment: @Juken: The accepted answer for this question includes `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. So does the accepted answer for the duplicated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for the current date:

```
WHERE TransactionDate = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Or if you prefer ANSI standards:

```
WHERE TransactionDate = cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)
```

Comment: TQ very much. both code works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Different sql implementations (ie SQL Server, Mysql, postgresql etc) can have different methods supported. For SQL Server the method you want to use is GETDATE() instead of CURDATE()

The documentation for this method is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from dbo.Student.studentProfile
    WHERE TransactionDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
        AND TransactionDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Comment: TQ for response. I already try the code you given. No error and no output, meanwhile have today date in my table.